# Postgres (DBeaver) reporting 0 changed rows after ST_Transform

Tags: postgresql, postgis, dbeaver

When I execute:

```
ALTER TABLE london_all_nodes ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(Point, 27700) USING ST_TRANSFORM(geom, 27700);
```

the Dbeaver statistics window reports `Updated Rows = 0`

When I check the data with

```
SELECT * FROM london_all_nodes LIMIT 5;
```

the geom column looks transformed as expected but it seems like `updated rows` should be equal to the number of rows in the table no?

Comment: I don't think an ALTER TABLE statement returns the number of modified rows, so DBeaver can't really display that information. I makes no sense to me to show `updated rows` for any DDL statement

Comment: good enough for me, thanks. Just sanity checking the outcome a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per @a_horse_with_no_name's comment, and confirmed by the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-altertable.html) "ALTER TABLE changes the definition of an existing table." `ALTER TABLE` acts on a column, not any individual rows.

Thus every cell in the column is changed but it considers the rows to be unchanged.